# Retrieving meta-box from a custom-post-type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, metabox

I am trying to display data from a custom post type on my home page, for which I am using a separate template.

I'm getting a Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Query::have_post() when my code looks like this:

```
get_header(); ?>
<div class="home_main_text">

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'home' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php 
$current = date("d/m/Y");
$args = array('post_type' => 'jh_dedications');
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

    while ( $loop -> have_post() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while ( $loop -> have_post() ) : $loop->the_post();`

Your missing an s `have_post()` should be `have_posts();`

Your title says retrieving meta-box and I am assuming you mean the post_meta.  Which you use the [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function.

Comment: how do I retrieve meta-box data within this loop?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean post_meta data. See updated answer.